# Redirect domain from example.net to example.com

Tags: domain, redirect

I'm currently using the Linode DNS Manager but I'm failing to see where can I adjust that if the user goes to example.net, he's automatically redirected to example.com. I know apache does that and my Apache is already configured properly at ServerAlias example.net and ServerName example.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user experience to see only example.com, rather than just having example.net work exactly like example.com, then setting up a separate virtual host in apache with a simple redirect rule that redirects everything is probably what you want.  With ServerAliases you can make several different names (www.example.com, example.com, www.example.net, example.net) work the same way but with Redirect rule you can force everything into one name that you support.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyy>
ServerName xxx.net
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xxx.com$1 [L,R=301]
...
...
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Just a note about the formatting for others who seek this same answer, the correct code should have RewriteRule written together, like this:

`<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyy>
ServerName xxx.net
RewriteEngine On
RewrituleRule ^(.*)$ http://xxx.com$1 [L,R=301]
...
...
...
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: huh. that's a pretty egregious typo on my part. fixed.